# How can I assign Time into time variable from edittext which takes string value?

Tags: java, android-studio

This is where I am picking time from TimePicker and it works perfectly fine but I cannot get it in time variable.

```
eText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = cldr.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minutes = cldr.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                // time picker dialog
                picker = new TimePickerDialog(AddMeeting.this,
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker tp, int sHour, int sMinute) {
                                eText.setText(sHour + ":" + sMinute);
                            }
                        }, hour, minutes, true);
                picker.show();
                //time1 = eText.getText().toTime();
            }
        });
        final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Comment: _"Time into time variable from edittext which takes string value"_ what now?

Answer (score 0):

Use `set` methods in `Calendar` instance.

```
...    
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker tp, int sHour, int sMinute) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sHour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sMinute);
    
    Date d = cal.getTime();
}
...
```

Comment: Sorry but I dont need value in Date d, I want it in Time time.

Comment: Which `Time`? can you specify the full package name of the `Time` class?